# Need support constructing an SQL query

Tags: sql

If a user orders an article which has a Qty (length) > 6, we check if there are articles < 6 in the stpPicklistItems (could be from other customers as well).

In case there are no articles > 6 Machine A is used (small one). But if there are articles > 6, Machine B is used for articles > 6 and also < 6 (large machine for both)

Every line in this table is a order from a different customer.
ID 02 is an order for 7m of fabric. This fabric is cut on machine B (> 6 m)
Smaller length are cut on machine A. But if there is an order > 6 m, every
order is cut on Machine B. Otherwise we have to cut the same article on two different machines.

I tried this:

```
SELECT EanUpc, Qty,
IF(a.Qty > 6, 'B','A') as Machine
FROM stpPicklistItems a

WHERE a.EanUpc IN (
SELECT DISTINCT EanUpc

FROM stpPicklistItems a2 
WHERE a2.Qty > 6
AND EanUpc = '2000000312040'
)
```

[image: enter query Result]

Because there is an order > 6m the Flag "Machine" should show B. If < 6 AND no orders > 6 it should be 'A'.

I am using MySQL

Comment: Have you attempted an answer yet?  Can you share any sample data with us?

Comment: Try this:  `SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE Qty > 6`

Comment: please consider adding sample table data and the expected result in formatted text. 
Also show us your current query attempt

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: It's not so easy. Of course I tried. But my problem is the 2nd condition. WHERE Qty > 6 is obvious one part of the SELECTION but the tricky part is IF the condition is true, to select all other articles. The condition is false, if no article with a certain article number is < 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working solution, which did the classification.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
a.EanUpc, a.ItemName, a.Qty,
CASE 
WHEN (SELECT count(*) 
        FROM stpPicklistItems a2 
        WHERE a2.EanUpc = a.EanUpc 
        AND a2.Qty > 6) >= 1 
THEN 'B'
ELSE 'A' 
END AS Machine
FROM stpPicklistItems a
ORDER BY a.EanUpc DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Like so;

```
SELECT *
FROM [Articles] a
WHERE a.ArticleNumber IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ArticleNumber 
    FROM [Articles] a2 
    WHERE a2.Qty > 6
)
```

Edit: Still guessing as you have not provided sample data or an expected result dataset but you could try this;

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    EanUpc,
    CASE WHEN (SELECT Count(*) 
               FROM [Articles] a2 
               WHERE a2.EanUpc = a.EanUpc 
               AND a2.Qty > 6) >= 1 
    THEN 'B' ELSE 'A' AS Machine
FROM [Articles] a
```

Comment: No, unfortunately not.. because it just show results, if there is any article > 6 in the 2nd SELECT.

I have updated the question.

Comment: @MarLon Don't understand what you mean... please include sample data and results or you will not get a meaningful answer

Comment: Any ideas? I struggle with setting the Machine Type. If no article > 6 is found, it should display all articles < 6 with the Machine type 'A' set.

Comment: @MarLon as I have told you, you won't get a sensible answer unless you provide sample data and results... Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MarLon see my edit, and if it is not correct then try to provide a subset of your data (formatted as per the link I provided above, and expected results for that data)

Comment: your last answer was almost perfect. I tried it with a CASE before, but, I messed it up. Thanks a lot!